# Eliminar "\n" de una lista en python

Tags: python, lista, archivo

estoy intentando abrir un archivo de texto y pasarlo a una lista, el archivo contiene varios numeros, por ejemplo: 
`1
2
3
4
5
6`

el problema es que al imprimir la lista sale con el salto de línea, así: 
['2\n', '1\n', '1\n', '-3\n', '1\n', '6']

y necesito eliminar ese **\n** , mi código es el siguiente:

````
    lista=[]
    archivo=open("numeros.txt","r")
    for linea in archivo.readlines():
        lista=lista+[linea]
    archivo.close()
    print(lista)```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unas observaciones:

- No uses `readlines` si no necesitas cargar en memoria todas las lineas del fichero simultáneamente. Raramente es necesario, solo en casos como ordenamientos lo es.
- Para eliminar el carácter de nueva línea usa `str.rstrip()`.
- Considera usar el administrador de contexto y `with` para cerrar el archivo automáticamente, la ventaja es que se cierra aún con excepciones de por medio y no corres el riesgo de olvidarte de llamar a `close`.
- Si quieres convertir las cadenas a enteros no necesitas usar siquiera `str.rstrip`. `int()` no necesita que se elimine.
- Por norma general no uses `lista=lista+[linea]` para agregar items a una lista, es muy ineficiente. `[linea]` crea una lista nueva en cada iteración solo para luego concatenearla con la anterior, además a continuación el GC tiene que eliminarla de memoria. Usa `list.append` o en éste caso una lista por compresión.

---

**`Lista de enteros`**

```
with open("numeros.txt", "r") as archivo:
    lista = [int(linea) for linea in archivo]

print(lista)
```

**`Lista de cadenas`**

```
with open("numeros.txt", "r") as archivo:
    lista = [linea.rstrip() for linea in archivo]

print(lista)
```

Versiones usando programación funcional (`map`):

**`Lista de enteros`**

```
with open("numeros.txt", "r") as archivo:
    lista = list(map(int, archivo))

print(lista)
```

**`Lista de cadenas`**

```
with open("numeros.txt", "r") as archivo:
    lista = list(map(str.rstrip, archivo))

print(lista)
```